# Is there any way to trace back a javascript function call?

Tags: javascript, function

I need a definitive way to figure out what Javascript is modifying a form value? The best I've been able to do is:

```
$(function(){
    console.log($("input[name=Email]").val());
});
```

But the value has not been changed by the point that this executes.

Comment: is this for debugging? if so maybe use a browsers development tools to set a break point and step through your code?

Comment: this will be executed when dom loaded.. is that you want ??

Comment: It's not my code, or at least I can't locate where it is in the hundreds of lines. If I swap my jQuery version from 1.3.2 (what the site is currently on) to 1.7.1, the input starts being changed.

Comment: Use `console.trace` I added an answer below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a new way to do this in Chrome and Firefox: `console.trace`

See here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.trace

In web inspector:

```
> console.trace()
console.trace() VM251:2
(anonymous function) VM251:2
InjectedScript._evaluateOn VM223:581
InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap VM223:540
InjectedScript.evaluate VM223:459
undefined
```

So to modify the accepted answer:

```
$('input#myInputAbove').change(function(){
    console.trace(); // No breakpoint needed anymore.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert this directly below the HTML of the form element you want to trace:

```
$('input#myInputAbove').change(function(){
    console.log('change detected'); // Breakpoint on this line
});
```

Use FireBug to insert a [breakpoint](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) into the above JS method. Hit it and take a look at the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

The following will show you what event handlers have been bound to a element:

```
$.each($("input[name='Email']").data('events'), function(i, event){
  $.each(event, function(i, handler){
      console.log( handler.handler );
  });
});
```

Comment: sorry, not `.fn`, but `.handler`

Answer (score -1):

```
prev_value = document.getElementByName('Email').value;

$("input[name=Email]").change(function(){
    var cur_value = document.getElementById('Email').value;
    if(cur_value != prev_value){
       alert("Value changed");
     //or console.log("Value changed"); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: I need a way to find out _what_ is modifying the value, not that it's being modified.

Comment: @BenDauphinee It's rough to -1 when I'm just trying to help you, even if I did not understand you well. you can just not to accept my answer

Comment: I'm not using the downvote as personal attack. It's within the guidelines to downvote an answer that is not correct for the question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112664